# AWS Sagemaker Life Cycle Configuration - AutoStop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have created 4 instances in my AWS sagemaker NOTEBOOKS tab.

I want to create a life cycle configuration where the instance should stop every day at 9:00 PM.

I have seen some examples but it is with IDLE TIME but not with the specific time

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# PARAMETERS
IDLE_TIME=3600

echo "Fetching the autostop script"
wget -O autostop.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariokostelac/sagemaker-setup/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py

echo "Starting the SageMaker autostop script in cron"
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 $DIR/autostop.py --time ${IDLE_TIME} | tee -a /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/auto-stop-idle.log'") | crontab -

echo "Changing cloudwatch configuration"
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariokostelac/sagemaker-setup/master/scripts/publish-logs-to-cloudwatch/on-start.sh | sudo bash -s auto-stop-idle /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/auto-stop-idle.log
```

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the crontab syntax to `0 21 * * * shutdown.py`

Then create a shutdown.py which is reduced version of the [autostop.py](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py) and contains mainly:

```
...
print('Closing notebook')
client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
client.stop_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName=get_notebook_name())
```

BTW: triggering `shutdown now` directly from the crontab command didn't work for me, therefore calling the SageMaker API instead.